# Sub string cannot be resolved Android

Tags: android

I am getting array list from Global class and getting value with index , but i am getting error on sub-string is that (Sub-string cannot be resolved).

```
Glide.with(ChooseCategoryProductsActivity.this)
     .load("file:///" + GlobalClass.IMAGES_PATH + "/" + GlobalClass.categoriesAr.get(GlobalClass.currentIndex)
     .substring(categoriesAr.get(GlobalClass.currentIndex)
     .lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
     .placeholder(R.drawable.stub)
     .into(categoryImage);
```

**Category class :**

```
public class Category {

public String catId = "";
public String catName = "";
public String catImage = "";
public String catDesc = "";
public String displayOrder = "";
public String createdDate = "";
public ArrayList<Product> productsAr = new ArrayList<Product>();

public Category(String catId, String catName, String catImage, String catDesc, String displayOrder, String createdDate) {

    this.catId = catId;
    this.catName = catName;
    this.catImage = catImage;
    this.catDesc = catDesc;
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
   }
}
```

Comment: what is type of **categoriesAr** declared ?

Comment: ArrayList with model class like **ArrayList<Category> categoriesAr = new ArrayList<Category>();**

Comment: Can you add your `Category` class ?

Comment: change substring to subString

Comment: Sidenote: static class variables are not a recommended way to store variables in Android

Comment: post your **Category**  class as well

Answer (score 1):

As you Declared

```
ArrayList<Category> categoriesAr = new ArrayList<Category>();
```

**`subString()`** is only applied on `String` not on custom object

Comment: Thanks for the information , i have added my answer there so can you check if is it right or not ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method called `subString()` with glide as far as i know and hence the compile time error `Sub string cannot be resolved`. `subString` works with `String`

Answer (score 0):

**So finally i did just like following, but i don't know whether is it right or not** :

```
    GlobalClass.categoriesAr.get(GlobalClass.currentIndex).toString().substring(categoriesAr.get(GlobalClass.currentIndex)
```

Comment: it is not right it will give you String representation of `Category` class which will not help you get the `image` name